# how to get details from a particular Samsung firmware

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

I need to extract some information from a given Samsung S7 Galaxy firmware such as build number, if it is 64-bit or not, baseband full version of the ROM. I am using Ubuntu with heimdall. Is there anything else I need to get this info?
Thanks